# Inrush current in the Boost Converter during start

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, inrush-current

[image]I am making a 400V 1kW boost converter but in the LT-SPICE simulation, it is drawing a huge current of 50-60A at the start for 1ms-3ms, but the current comes down to 12A after that.
The inductor current rating is 20A and I will be making PCB trace for 25-30A rating. I am afraid that the large current at the start might damage the costly components and PCB trace.

Please suggest me how to solve the problem and what do people do In practical boost converters?

Comment: add current sensing and turn the switch off when the limit is hit,

Comment: Input L and shunt PWM is used also for soft start

Comment: It's the initial charging of the capacitor that takes a big surge. Maybe post you schematic if you want a better response?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 that question is unrelated.

Comment: Yes, It's the initial charging current so even though the duty cycle is 0, the larger current will flow until the output voltage is equal to the input voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka It's normal boost convertor that I simulated in LTSPICE to see the initial current, I have not completed the schematic.

Comment: If you have simulated it then you have a good enough schematic to post.

Comment: Start with theory, specs 1st dI/dt, Q factor

Comment: Adding an NTC is often a solution to limit this in-rush current but a more efficient/modern version is the insertion of a resistance in series with the output capacitor and later on shorted by a ground-referenced MOSFET. Negative sensing on some recent PWM controllers prevents from having switching operation until the surge is gone. Inserting a bypass diode across the inductor and the catch diode (a direct path from the input to output, avoiding inductor saturation) will also help and it is a common industrial solution.

Comment: I'm afraid @Manish is not correct. If you start with a lower duty cycle and increase it gradually while the output capacitors get charged, you should be ok, if suitable values are chosen.

Comment: @HarryH, you are right, if we start with a lower duty cycle it should be ok but the problem is, assume the duty cycle is 0 and you apply the input and as the output capacitor is discharged, it will act as a short circuit and a large current will flow to charge the capacitor up to the voltage level of the input.

Comment: @Manish Yes, you're correct. And I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>This problem is unrelated to the boost-control mechanism/circuit but can be made worse by it if the boost control circuit is activated before the output capacitors are charged to the input supply DC voltage. In other words, it's a regular inrush problem suffered by most circuits that seek to charge high value electrolytic capacitors from a high(ish) supply voltage.</sub>

> *Please suggest me how to solve the problem and what do people do In
> practical boost converters?*

The problem that you need to overcome is the initial inrush current and this is partially alleviated by R3 being 3 Ω: -

[image]

Ignoring the slight reducing-effect that the inductors will have, the inrush current is 200 volts divided by 3 Ω = 66 amps. OK, you are seeing 50 to 60 amps and this is due to the inductors being a reasonable blocking impedance on power up.

If you want to avoid this initial surge then using an [NTC thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter#Thermistor) can be a good choice. It has a fairly high initial (cold) resistance (several tens of Ω) dropping to sub Ω values within a few milliseconds as it warms over that short period in time.

Another method is to pre-charge the capacitors to the 200 volt supply voltage prior to switching in the main power circuit. Once the capacitors are charged, you have full control of currents via the boost mechanism.

Comment: could you suggest me an NTC thermistor for this requirement? and how much time NTC thermistor takes? if it drops its resistance within 2-3 ms then it might damage the components.

Comment: @Manish not off the top of my head I can't and anyway, I might suggest this one or that one and you might not have a model for it in your spice library and then you'd be scratching your head how i found the one I suggested and you'd ask me again and, in the end, you might just be better off finding one yourself. Also, I might find one in 30 minutes of my time then, you might realize that it isn't available in Tirupati and so I would be wasting my time. Better for you to find one and ask me it it looks suitable. That would be the preferred process for this site too.